# What's the name of "<<-JS" operator

Tags: ruby

I have seen following in one gem:

```
handler = <<-JS
   function(cmp){
    this.cmp = cmp;
   }
  JS
```

javascript inside is correctly highlited by IDE, so probably it's well-known language construction
And I'd like to know more about this mechanism? operator?. But I can't even google it to learn about it. Any advice?

Comment: It's called a [`HEREDOC`](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html)

Comment: More informations can be found in [literals documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents)